# no session.getTransaction method is not there

Tags: java, hibernate

![enter image description here][1]      SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(student);
        session.get
        [image: code error screenshot]

I get this error while I try to call this getTransaction method of session so that I can commit the transaction.how do I rectify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To commit transaction you will need `Transaction` object which will returned by `session.beginTransaction();`.

Change your code as follows:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(); Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction(); //org.hibernate.Transaction
session.save(student);
tx.commit();
```

**Update**

It is good practice to use proper `try-catch` block:

```
public boolean saveStudent(Student student)
    {
    Session session=null;
    Transaction tx=null;
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
        try 
    {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
        tx = session.beginTransaction(); 
        session.save(student);
        tx.commit();
        return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
    {
         if(tx!=null && tx.isActive())
         {
          tx.rollback();//rolebacks the currect active transaction
         }
        return false;
        }
     finally 
    {
         if(session!=null && session.isOpen())
         {
           session.close();
         }
         if(tx!=null)
         {
           tx=null;
         }
        }
      }
```

Comment: calling `buildSessionFactory` on each call is also not good practice.You should create another class let say named `HibernateHelper` from where you will get `session` by calling method `HibernateHelper.getsession()` and this `HibernateHelper` is having code of lets say connection pooling,building session factory etc.